# Selenium tests, how would you do?

Tags: testing, selenium, junit

I'm thinking about the best way to do the following kind of tests with selenium and I wanted asking how you would do.
I have 2 different clients in the system that I have to check, the first one offers something to sell and the second one has to do an offer. The offer can be accepted or declined.

#### Example.

- **Person 1**: I want to sell a car so I put my car with all its details onto the system.
- **Person 2**: I want to buy a car so I search for a car, I see the car of person 1 so I do an offer. On my dashboard is showed that I did an offer.
- **Person 1**: I access to my dashboard and I notice that there is an offer, I see the offer, I decline because I don't like it.
- **Person 2**: I access to my dashbord and I notice that the offer has been declined, I make another offer.
- **Person 1**: I access my dashbord and I notice the new offer, I like it, I accept.

How would you organize the tests with selenium??

Comment: Is this one whole test case, or can it be split up? Are you saying that the entire test case is to ensure a user can accept or decline an offer?

Comment: It can split up, but I don't know how to automate the whole process.  I'm new with selenium and I don't know how to automate the messaging system, in a way that the tests can run and run again...Every time an offer is accepted it is no more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider your example as 5 separate user stories. You can create a separate automated test for each of these stories. For this purpose, you would have to define preconditions for the test and the desired outcome.

For example, for the 1st story there are no preconditions, other than the trivial ones, like a user with such and such username exists and has privileges to sell cars. You will have to script the process of putting car details into your system using Selenium. The desired outcome is the car is in the system (can be searched for or shows up in the full list of cars for sale) and its attributes match what was entered.

For the 2nd story a precondition is that there is a car for sale. You will have to ensure this either by submitting car for sale via the process you developed for the 1st story or by entering it bypassing UI, for example via business services layer or inserting directly into the database. The desired outcome is that the dashboard for user 2 shows the offer.

And so on.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, what do you mean for "business services layer", can you give me an example? Thanks!!

Comment: Web-based applications are usually structured into several tiers or layers. Among them there are, usually, an UI layer, a data persistense/data access layer, and a business layer that contains all the business logic of the application. Usually, but not always, may expose some API, so that you can interact with the application via either some kind of web service API or a proramming language level API, bypassing the UI layer.